# Estoy trabajando con pandas en python y tengo este error: TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy trabajando con Pandas y Numpy. Quiero hacer una función que me permita buscar los valores mayores a 23 de una columna, pero tengo este error: raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'> . Hice lo que me sugirieron en una pregunta que formulé anteriormente y me sale este nuevo error.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from tabulate import tabulate

fito = pd.read_csv('coastalDataClean.csv')
fito.columns = ['Date/Time', 'wave_height_significant', 'wave_height_max', 
'zero_upcross_wave_period', 'peak_energy_period', 'peak_direction_from_north_degrees', 
'sea_surface_temp_c']

print('\n--- Primeros 5 datos ---')
print(fito.head(5))

print('\n--- 5 datos aleatorios ---')
print(fito.sample(5))

print('\n--- Últimos 5 datos ---')
print(fito.tail(5))


#ESTA FUNCION PUEDE APLICARSE A CUALQUIER RANGO DE DATOS. SOLO BASTA CON CAMBIAR LOS VALORES DEL LOC.
x = fito.loc[96:130] 
temp = x.query('(sea_surface_temp_c > 23)')

print('\nEsta tabla muestra las fechas y horas en las que la temperatura fue mayor a 23 grados 
Celsius.')
print(tabulate(temp, tablefmt = 'grid'))

#---------------
fito['sea_surface_temp_c'] = int(fito['sea_surface_temp_c'])

if fito['sea_surface_temp_c'] > 23:
    print(fito[int('sea_surface_temp_c')].sample(5))  
#Esta última función es la que me tira error. Yo quiero imprimir solo los 
#valores de esa columna que sean mayores a 23.
```